# DataTables pagination could be over the Bootstrap Fixed Footer of the ASP.NET Core MVC project template

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, datatables

I am working with ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and Bootstrap 4.4.1 and the default project template with DataTables.js (1.10.20 and css twitter bootstrap).

The first thing I must say is that I'm not good at all with css, so I think this could be the reason of this problem.

The following problem occurs when the screen has a lower resolution: (Tested resolution: 400x500)

[image: Footer behind pagination]

I would like to know why this happened with the Fixed Footer and if there is a fix for this.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```css
a.navbar-brand {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
    color: #0366d6;
}


.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebApplication1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand">WebApplication1</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />

<div class="table-responsive p-1">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="Table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    Name
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        Hello
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        World
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Table').DataTable(
                    {
                        "language": {
                            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/English.json"
                        }
                    });
                    
            });</script>
</div>
        </main>

    </div>
            <footer class="border-top footer text-muted text-center">
    <div class="container">
        Footer
    </div>
</footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CSS flex to reduce the change to your markup.

The change I did were:

1. I added class `content` to your main content.
2. I changed the style for `body` to have these styles

```
body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

3. Then I added these, and also updated the style for your `.footer`

```
header {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

```css
a.navbar-brand {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
    color: #0366d6;
}


.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand">WebApplication1</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="content container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />

<div class="table-responsive p-1">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="Table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    Name
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        Hello
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        World
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Table').DataTable(
                    {
                        "language": {
                            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/English.json"
                        }
                    });
                    
            });</script>
</div>
        </main>

    </div>
    <footer class="footer border-top footer text-muted text-center">
        <div class="container">
            Footer
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

You can see it working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ba9cdxe/

Comment: Thanks, this has the behavior I expected. I read that these kind of things are tricky.

Comment: @AndrésQuesadaCascante It just needs getting used to. [There are other ways to do it](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/), but what I suggested seems easiest in your case

Comment: Tha's right, it's kind of funny because so far I finally see a footer that really does what it should (Regardless of the layout the page uses)

Answer (score 0):

you can change the position of the footer to static then it will be fixed.

Comment: I changed it as you mentioned and it covers all the free space too (half page is footer now).

Comment: then max-height to footer may helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Currently I already marked an answer as correct with what I needed. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try remove posistion:absolute in footer class

```
.footer {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

Comment: The problem now is that the footer takes up all the free space on the page (Depending on the page you visit, it can cover more or less space). Is there any other way for me to keep the starting position?